# Losing accuracy with double division

Tags: double

I am having a problem with a simple division from two integers. I need it to be as accurate as possible, but for some reason the double type is working strange.

For example, if I execute the following code:

```
double res = (29970.0/1000.0);
```

The result is 29.969999999999999, when it should be 29.970.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea why this is happening?

Because double representation is finite. For example, [IEEE754 double-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary64) standard has 52 bits for fraction. So, not all the real numbers are covered. So, some of the values can not be ideally precise. In your case the result is 10^-15 away from the ideal.

Comment: `So, the values will be always not ideally precise.` is incorrect. Sometimes the values will be ideally precise.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev Yep, I straighten this out.

Answer (score 2):

> I need it to be as accurate as possible

You shouldn't use `double`s, then. In Java, for example, you would use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead (most languages provide a similar facility). `double` operations are intrinsically inaccurate to some degree. This is due to the [internal representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_number#Internal_representation) of [floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_number).

Comment: Unless, of course, you're trying to calculate something like `1./3.` which will be imprecise in both representations.

Comment: Decimal variables will work better with numbers that have short decimal representations (e.g., money amounts), but of course they also have intrinsically limited precision, just like floating point numbers.  For a value like pi, the achieved precision of a floating point versus a decimal variable will depend mainly on the number of bytes the compiler uses for that particular variable type.

Answer (score 0):

floating point numbers of type float and double are stored in binary format. Therefore numbers cant have precise decimal values. Those values are instead quantisized. If you hypothetically had only 2 bits fraction number type you would be able to represent only 2^-2 quantums: 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75, nothing between.

Answer (score 0):

> I need it to be as accurate as possible

There is no silver bullet, but if you want only basic arithmetic operations (which map ℚ to ℚ), and you REALLY want exact results, then your best bet is rational type composed of two unlimited integers (a.k.a. BigInteger, BigInt, etc.) - but even then, memory is not infinite, and you must think about it.

For the rest of the question, please read about fixed size floating-point numbers, there's plenty of good sources.